# Erlang: whether two lists have a common element

Tags: erlang

```
a = [1, 2, 3],
b = [4, 5, 6],
c = [1, 7, 8],
```

`has_common_element(a, b)` is `false` since there are no common elements between the two arrays.

`has_common_element(a, c)` is `true` since there is at least one common element (1) between the two arrays.

I can use [`lists:member`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2) to check whether a single element is in the list. How do I implement `has_common_element` in Erlang to check whether two lists have a common element?

Answer (score 4):

Create sets from the lists and use `sets:is_disjoint`:

```
has_common_member(L1, L2) ->
    not(sets:is_disjoint(sets:from_list(L1), sets:from_list(L2))).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension like below:

```
test(A, B)->
    [] /= [X || X <- A, Y <- B, X == Y].
```

the result in shell:

```
1> A = [1, 2, 3].
[1,2,3]
2> B = [4, 5, 6].
[4,5,6]
3> C = [1, 7, 8].
[1,7,8]
4> foo:test(A, B).
false
5> foo:test(A, C).
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make fast solution using `erlang:--/2` operator:

```
has_common_element(A, B) when length(B) > length(A) ->
    has_common_element(B, A); % not necessary optimization but helps for very uneven sets
has_common_element(A, B) ->
    A =/= A -- B.
```

It will be O(N*M) in older versions but since OTP21 I think it becomes O((N+M)*logM) (I can't find relevant release note just now). Benchmark for yourself in the version you are using and choose properly.

Anyway You can make still pretty fast O((N+M)*logM) solution using maps:

```
has_common_element(A, B) when length(B) > length(A) ->
    has_common_element(B, A); % not necessary optimization but helps for very uneven sets
has_common_element(A, B) ->
    M = maps:from_list([{X,[]} || X <- B]),
    any_in_map(M, A).

any_in_map(_, []) -> false;
any_in_map(M, [H|T]) ->
    maps:is_key(H, M) orelse any_in_map(M, T).
```

And there is a nasty slightly faster version of previous using process_dictionary. You can use it directly when you have good control over list elements and process_dictionary doesn't bother you (usually not good idea in OTP process).

```
has_common_element_dirty(A, B) when length(B) > length(A) ->
    has_common_element_dirty(B, A); % not necessary optimization but helps for very uneven sets
has_common_element_dirty(A, B) ->
    [put(X, []) || X <- B],
    any_in_dict(A).

any_in_dict([]) -> false;
any_in_dict([H|T]) ->
    [] =:= get(H) orelse any_in_dict(T).
```

You can wrap it in the linked process and make it safe:

```
has_common_element(A, B) ->
    Self = self(),
    Ref = make_ref(),
    Pid = spawn_link(fun() -> Self ! {Ref, has_common_element_dirty(A, B)} end),
    receive {Ref, Result} -> Result end.
```

Benchmark for your application and list sizes and choose accordingly because all those solutions have different GC and raw performance characteristics. Usually, the first one should be sufficient.

```
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> Size=100000, A = [rand:uniform(Size*10000) || _ <- lists:duplicate(Size, 0)], B = [rand:uniform(Size*10000) || _ <- lists:duplicate(Size, 0)], C = [rand:uniform(Size*10000)+Size*10000 || _ <- lists:duplicate(Size, 0)], ok.
ok
2> timer:tc(fun() -> A =/= A -- B end).
{77943,true}
3> timer:tc(fun() -> A =/= A -- C end).
{44325,false}
```

It's less than 100ms for comparing two 100k lists. It's on par or better than the best (s2) from [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635979/pascal)'s solutions. Note OTP22 version.

Comment: Interesting to learn that --/2 has been improved for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Both @bxdoan and @choroba solutions work and are very concise. You do not give information about the size of the lists and their content, and it may be important.

The solution with list comprehension tests a list which size is the cross product of the 2 input list and thus gets very slow with big input lists. The solution with sets grows less faster. I propose you another one, less concise, but which behaves better for longer lists. I also add a solution using lists:member (not efficient) and another using maps (similar to sort).

```
-module (inter).

-export ([test/2,s1/2,s2/2,s3/2,s4/2,s5/2]).



test(Method,Size) ->
    A = [rand:uniform(Size*10000) || _ <- lists:duplicate(Size, 0)],
    % B may contain common element with A
    B = [rand:uniform(Size*10000) || _ <- lists:duplicate(Size, 0)],
    % C is by construction disjoint with A
    C = [rand:uniform(Size*10000)+Size*10000 || _ <- lists:duplicate(Size, 0)],
    io:format("test algorithm ~s~n",[method(Method)]),
    {test(Method,A,B),test(Method,A,C)}.


test(M,L1,L2) ->
    timer:tc(?MODULE, M, [L1,L2]).

method(s1) ->
    "List comprehension";
method(s2) ->
    "List sorted";
method(s3) ->
    "List to set";
method(s4) ->
    "List to map";
method(s5) ->
    "lists:member".

s1(L1,L2) ->
    [] =/= [X || X <- L1, Y <- L2, X =:= Y].


s2(L1,L2) ->
    s2_help(lists:sort(L1),lists:sort(L2)).

s2_help([],_) -> false;
s2_help(_,[]) -> false;
s2_help([_A|_],[_A|_]) -> true;
s2_help([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) when H1 > H2 -> s2_help([H1|T1],T2);
s2_help(L1,L2) -> s2_help(tl(L1),L2).

s3(L1,L2) -> 
    not(sets:is_disjoint(sets:from_list(L1), sets:from_list(L2))).

s4(L1,L2) ->
    s4_help(lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> maps:put(X, 0, Acc) end,#{},L1),L2).

s4_help(_,[]) -> false;
s4_help(Map,[H|T]) ->
    case maps:is_key(H, Map) of
        true -> true;
        false -> s4_help(Map,T)
    end.

s5([],_) -> false;
s5([H|T],L2) ->
    case lists:member(H, L2) of
        true -> true;
        false -> s5(T,L2)
    end.
```

and then the results:

```
55> c(inter).             
{ok,inter}
56> inter:test(s1,100).   
test algorithm List comprehension
{{0,false},{0,false}}
57> inter:test(s2,100).   
test algorithm List sorted
{{0,false},{0,false}}
58> inter:test(s3,100).   
test algorithm List to set
{{0,false},{0,false}}
59> inter:test(s1,1000).
test algorithm List comprehension
{{16000,true},{0,false}}
60> inter:test(s2,1000).
test algorithm List sorted
{{0,false},{0,false}}
61> inter:test(s3,1000).
test algorithm List to set
{{0,false},{0,false}}
62> inter:test(s1,10000).
test algorithm List comprehension
{{468999,false},{484000,false}}
63> inter:test(s2,10000).
test algorithm List sorted
{{15000,false},{0,false}}
64> inter:test(s3,10000).
test algorithm List to set
{{31000,false},{32000,false}}
65> inter:test(s1,100000).
test algorithm List comprehension
{{48515953,true},{48030953,false}}
66> inter:test(s2,100000).
test algorithm List sorted
{{62000,true},{78000,false}}
67> inter:test(s3,100000).
test algorithm List to set
{{1233999,true},{1296999,false}}
...
69> inter:test(s4,100).   
test algorithm List to map
{{0,false},{0,false}}
70> inter:test(s4,1000).
test algorithm List to map
{{0,false},{0,false}}
71> inter:test(s4,10000).
test algorithm List to map
{{0,false},{16000,false}}
72> inter:test(s4,100000).
test algorithm List to map
{{62000,true},{78000,false}}
73> inter:test(s5,100).   
test algorithm lists:member
{{0,false},{0,false}}
74> inter:test(s5,1000).
test algorithm lists:member
{{0,false},{0,false}}
75> inter:test(s5,10000).
test algorithm lists:member
{{31000,true},{171999,false}}
76> inter:test(s5,100000).
test algorithm lists:member
{{921000,true},{19031980,false}}
77>
```

Comment: You can use `lists:usort/1` instead of `lists:sort/1`.

Comment: Try out `A =/= A -- B` ;-)